# Change color to an All Day Event in google calendar with Apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I've got a problem to change the color in an All Day Event in google calendar with google apps script.
I tested a lot of way to go, but nothing works.

var event = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendrierId).createAllDayEvent(title,date).addPopupReminder(1440);

Does anyone has a solution

Thanks

Comment: I believe you can only set the colour for the entire calendar, not specific events. Logically it should be in the EventSeries object, but seems like there is no option there either.

Comment: Hi Vytautas, it's possible for a standard event, why not for an all day event ?

Comment: Regular event and all day event are the same, whatever applies to the regular one will also apply to the all day one. As far as I can see, you cannot set colors for any events at all

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar) (That must be [enabled before use](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced). In the Script Editor select Resources > Advanced Google services... and then enable it in the Google Developers Console.)

Once enabled you can create an event using the 
[Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) and use **colorId** to set the color of the event, here's an example:

```
function myFunction() {
  var calendarId = '{YOUR_CALENDAR_ID}';
  var date = "2016-12-25";
  var event = {
    summary: 'Christmas Day',
    location: 'Home',
    start: {
      date: date
    },
    end: {
      date: date
    },
    // Bold Red background.
    colorId: 11
  };
  Calendar.Events.insert(event, calendarId);
}
```

As of today, there are 11 colors available for events, you can use [Calendar.Colors.get()](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get) for the full list, but here's a table with the names used in the UI that you're probably more familiar with:

```
|    name    | colorId | background |
|------------|---------|------------|
| Blue       |    1    |   #a4bdfc  |
| Turquoise  |    2    |   #7ae7bf  |
| Purple     |    3    |   #dbadff  |
| Red        |    4    |   #ff887c  |
| Yellow     |    5    |   #fbd75b  |
| Orange     |    6    |   #ffb878  |
| Turquoise  |    7    |   #46d6db  |
| Gray       |    8    |   #e1e1e1  |
| Bold Blue  |    9    |   #5484ed  |
| Bold Green |    10   |   #51b749  |
| Bold Red   |    11   |   #dc2127  |
```

Comment: Yep, this looks right. Was planning to look into using Calendar API, but didn't have enough time to check and write an answer. But from what I have read this would be the only way to go (similarly how I had to go through Gmail API to fetch messages instead of threads)